# Finding last item in a line using grep

Tags: command-line, grep

I'm attempting to take the last word or phrase using grep for a specific pattern. In this example, it would be the from the last comma to the end of the line:

```
Blah,3,33,56,5,Foo 30,,,,,,,3,Great Value
```

And so the wanted output for that line would be "Great Value". All the lines are different lengths as well, but always have a single comma preceding the last words.

Basically, I would like to simply output from the last comma to the end of the line. Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using `awk -F, '{print $NF}'`?

Comment: Getting last item on the line is easy task, but how should that line be identified ? i mean, how can a command or script look at the line, and say "yep, that's the one" ? what's the pattern that identifies that line ?

Comment: `grep` is not the tool for this job.

Comment: @Kusalananda         we can make use of `rev` command also right then cut first part then re `rev` the output

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here:

```
grep -o '[^,]\+$'
```

- `[^,]\+` matches one or more characters that are not `,` at the end of the line (`$`)
- `-o` prints only the matched portion

**Example:**

```
% grep -o '[^,]\+$' <<<'Blah,3,33,56,5,Foo 30,,,,,,,3,Great Value'
Great Value
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was trying to use a combination of "." and other expressions before but this works a lot better, much appreciated.

Comment: hmm, I'd have used `-Eo` and then not needed to escape the `+`

Comment: @Baldrickk `-E` enables ERE, that's why.

Comment: @heemayl yeah, I know why.  I tend to use it as it is a more common regex syntax

Answer (score 17):

Always like to see an `awk` solution so here it is (upvoted the proper solution!):

```
% awk -F, '{print $NF}'  <<<'Blah,3,33,56,5,Foo 30,,,,,,,3,Great Value'
Great Value
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. While you can use grep, you can also drive a screw with a hammer.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will give you the desired output

**Command :**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Blah,3,33,56,5,Foo 30,,,,,,,3,Great Value" | rev | awk -F',' '{ print $1 }' | rev
```

**Output :**

```
Great Value
```

Tested on this website : https://rextester.com/KNMI75463